# JOLT: How to transform a list only if it is not empty

Tags: json, jolt

I want to transform a JSON array using a JOLT specification.

**My input:**

```json
[
  {
    "list": [ "item1" ]
  }
]
```

**My desired output:**

```json
[
  {
    "list": [
      {
        "listType": "1",
        "listValue": "item1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The goal is to transform every entry to a JSON object containing a type attribute.

This is my jolt spec so far:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "list": {
          "*": {
            "#1": "[&3].&2[&1].listType",
            "@(0)": "[&3].&2[&1].listValue"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And this works fine as long as the list is non-empty. However, if I pass an empty list `"list": []` the attribute will be ignored in the transformed JSON. In this case, I would want to convert this to an empty list in my output as well, i.e. the desired transformation for this attribute would also be `"list": []`.

I found a couple of suggestions trying to achieve this with a default specification, but the thing is that I don't want an empty list to be added *if the attribute is not present in the original JSON*. In this case, I don't want to see this field in the output. I only want to see an empty list, if there was an empty list in the input in the first place.

Is this possible? I would also be happy with a solution that requires a null value instead of an empty list, i.e. `"list": null` would transform to `"list": []` if this would be easier.

**Edit**: A few more examples of what I am trying to achieve:

**Case 1:**

```json
[
  {
    "list": [
      "item1"
    ],
    "attribute2": "abc"
  }
]
```

should be transformed to

```json
[
  {
    "list": [
      {
        "listType": "1",
        "listValue": "item1"
      }
    ],
    "attribute2": "abc"
  }
]
```

**Case 2:**

```json
[
  {
    "list": [],
    "attribute2": "abc"
  }
]
```

should be transformed to

```json
[
  {
    "list": [],
    "attribute2": "abc"
  }
]
```

**Case 3**

```json
[
  {
    "attribute2": "abc"
  }
]
```

should be transformed to

```json
[
  {
    "attribute2": "abc"
  }
]
```

Note: No `list` attribute in Case 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "aaa",
      "*": {
        "list": {
          "*": {
            "#1": "bbb[&3].&2[&1].listType",
            "@(0)": "bbb[&3].&2[&1].listValue"
          }
        },
        "*": "bbb[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "aaa": {
        "@": "ccc[]",
        "*": {
          "list": {
            "*": {
              "@(5,bbb)": "ccc[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "ccc": "=lastElement"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ccc": ""
    }
  }
]
```

---

**Input 1:**

```json
[
  {
    "list": [
      "item1"
    ]
  }
]
```

**Output 1:**

```json
[ {
  "list": [ {
    "listType": "1",
    "listValue": "item1"
  } ]
} ]
```

---

**Input 2:**

```json
[
  {
    "list": []
  }
]
```

**Output 2:**

```json
[ {
  "list": []
} ]
```

---

**Input 3:**

```json
[
  {
    "list": null
  }
]
```

**Output 3:**

```json
[ {
  "list": null
} ]
```

---

**Input 4:**

```json
[
  {}
]
```

**Output 4:**

```json
[ {} ]
```

---

**Input 5:**

```json
[]
```

**Output 5:**

```json
[]
```

**First operation:**

First of all, we create a snapshot of all we have in the sample key like `aaa`. After that, we can loop through all of the input keys and transform them into the shape we want and finally save all of them into sample another key like `bbb`.

**Second operation:**

In this operation, we should merge all we have. so we can create a loop from our original input which means it is our snapshot or `aaa` key.

*Note 1:* We save both `aaa` and `bbb` values in a `ccc` key. so they merged together.

*Note 2:* If we have any issue with looping through `list`, we have just `aaa`'s value. otherwise, we have a second index in the `ccc`. So always we can get the last element as a valid transformed output.

**Third operation:**

We can get the last element from the `ccc` array as a valid output.

**Fourth operation:**

We should bring the `ccc` value to one level up to achieve our desired output.

Comment: Awesome, even though I don't really understand it. The only thing I see is that this does not pass through other attributes in case the list array is not empty (see case 1 in my edited question). Can this be modified accordingly?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thank you for updating, this is now working fine for all my use cases so I accepted this answer. Could you maybe add a short explanation of what's going on there so I can integrate it more easily into my (more complex) existing specifications?

Comment: @Jan I forgot to add a description. check the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the cases by using two objects labeled `"list"` and `"*"`(`else case`) in which the `"list"` array is replicated whenever the array is empty.

If the array `"list"` is non-empty, then we pick the first component of the returning array through use of **cardinality** spec, deriving from the `"list"` object such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "list": {
          "*": {
            "#1": "[&3].&2[&1][0].listType",
            "@(0)": "[&3].&2[&1][0].listValue"
          }
        },
        "*": {// else case
          "@1,list": "[&2].list[]",
          "@": "[&2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "list": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this also adds the "list" attribute even if it was not part of the original JSON, which is something I need to avoid (I need to distinguish between passing an empty list and passing no list attribute at all)

Comment: Thank you for that, I agree that it works fine for my posted examples, however it does only support one element in the list. In an attempt to reduce the complexity of the problem I gave only examples with one element, but I need a solution which works for lists with more than one element as well.

Comment: You're welcome, need to see for those specific cases @Jan Best wishes.